# Monte Carlo and Sampling

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, monte-carlo

Suppose that we have a finite state space $E$ and a distribution $\pi:E \rightarrow (0,1)$ with $\pi(x) >0$. The idea behind Monte Carlo is that we generate a Markov chain $X=(X_n,n\in \mathbb{N})$ with transition matrix $p$ such that $p$ is ergodic (irreducible and aperiodic) and that $\pi$ is the unique invariant distribution of $p$, so that the total variation $||p^n(x,y) -\pi(y)||_{TV} \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

**Question**.

However, I'm a little confused about the rigorous justification behind sampling. Suppose that we want to compute the expectation $\mathbb{E}f(Y)$ where $Y$ is a random variables with distribution $\pi$. Then I understand that $\mathbb{E}^x f(X_n) \rightarrow \mathbb{E} f(Y)$ for bounded $f$. But how do we approximate $\mathbb{E}^x f(X_n)$? I would assume that we would like to apply the strong law in "some way" with respect to the Markov chain $X$ so that almost surely, we have
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f(X_k) \rightarrow \mathbb{E}f(Y), \qquad n\rightarrow \infty
$$
Of course, this is not properly justified, since $X_1,...$ are not pairwise independent and identically distributed so we can't use the strong law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give some general direction on why we can apply the strong law of large numbers. The theorem for stationary stochastic processes that is analogous to the strong law of large numbers for an i. i. d. sequences is called the Birkhoff ergodic theorem.

It has that if $X_1, X_2,...$ is a stationary real-valued stochastic process that is ergodic, and $E(X_i) = \mu$, then $\bar{X} \rightarrow \mu$ almost surely.

This means given a Markov Chain, if for a fixed specification of transition probabilities there is a unique invariant distribution, then the strong law of large numbers holds for any initial distribution that is dominated by the invariant distribution.

We can make this apply to any initial distribution under a slightly stronger regularity condition than uniqueness of the invariant distribution. This is called Harris recurrence and with it the strong law of large numbers holds for any initial distribution.

Comment: After some reading about ergodic theory, it seems that by Birkhoff, we do not require that $p$ is aperiodic. It seems that as long as $p$ is irreducible and has invariant distribution $\pi$, then we can compute expectation $\mathbb{E}^\pi f(X_0)$ using the sample mean. Is this true?

Comment: Yes periodic chains can arise in MCMC and the strong law of large numbers still holds. I think an example of this can be see in _R.M. Neal (2004), Improving Asymptotic Variance of MCMC Estimators:Non-reversible Chains are Better. Technical Report No. 0406, Dept. of Statistics, University of Toronto_. Also for more on this type of technical detail of Markov chains you might see the book _Markov Chains and Stochastic Stability_ by S.P. Meyan and R.L. Tweedie.